# How to Write JPA annotation based select query where some parameter is null

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data

I want  to select list of chatrooms by `JPA` annotation **@query** where my updatedAt field is null. In Mysql we write 'is null' for something is null but in JPA what is the correct method for it . 
I mention my code which is correct or not . If not then how to provide value instead of 'is null' .

```
@Query("select cr from from Person m inner join m.chatRooms cr where m.id=?1 and cr.updatedAt is null")
List<ChatRoom> findAllNewChatRoomsOfPerson(Long personId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct.

In [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html) (Java Persistence Query Language), checking if a value is `NULL` is done the same way as in plane old SQL.

Check out [this](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/comparison#Comparing_NULL_values_) documentation

I should also point out that `@Query` is not a standard JPA feature, but a feature provided by the superb [Spring Data JPA project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/)

Comment: Thanks for the information about Spring Data JPA . It clear my concept about Spring Data JPA.

Comment: It would be helpful for future viewers if you accept the answer as correct so they don't have to red the comments. Thanks!